# Python class with variable parent class object

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Sorry that I am not using a general example to explain my problem. I know it has nothing to do with machine learning, but I tried to write a general example and it was a lot more confusing so I decided to go with that: I have two parent classes, let's say

```
class MLP(object):
    def __init__(self, mlp_architecture):
        ...
    def forward(self):
        ...
class CNN(object):
    def __init__(self, cnn_architecture):
        ...
    def forward(self):
        ...
```

and I have a child class, let's say

```
class Classifier(Model):
    def __init__(self, num_epochs, 
                       learning_rate,
                       ...
                       model_architecture):
        super(Classifier, self).__init__(model_architecture)
    def train(self):
        ...
    def predict(self, x):
        ...
```

Now `Classifier`'s methods work for both `MLP` and `CNN` and they require a `forward` method. I would like `Classifier` to be able to inherit `forward` from both `MLP` and `CNN` without having to define two child classes like this

```
class ClassifierMLP(MLP):
    ...
class ClassifierCNN(CNN):
    ...
```

Instead, I would like to do something like this (I know what I wrote is wrong, but I hope you get it)

```
clf = Classifier(MLP)(num_epochs=...,
                      learning_rate=...,
                      ...
                      model_architecture=...)
clf.train()
```

What would be the proper way to do this? Also, if you are wondering "why bother", `Classifier`, `MLP` and `CNN` actually have a lot more methods and I also have more Parent classes from which I would like Classifier to inherit, so I think my program would be much simpler if I was able to do this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what you want is a  `Classifier` that can have either methods from `MLP` or `CNN` [*mixed in*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)?

Comment: Python is very flexible language, you will definitely find a way to solve this using inheritance, but maybe "keep it simple" approach would be better? Try just to use composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: Maybe `MLP`/`CNN` should inherit from `Classifier`, not the other way around. Or you could add a normal member `model` to `Classifier` and pass either a `MLP` or a `CNN` in its constructor.

Comment: @dhke It's the first time I am earing of mixin so maybe I am wrong, but from what I understand it's inheriting methods from more than one class. In my case, `MLP` and `CNN` have almost the same methods (e.g. `forward()`). `forward()` have the same output type in both `MLP` and `CNN`, but the method _definition_ is not the same. So if I am inheriting from both classes, I would need a string variable, say `model_name`, to specify from which class to inherit (with a `if else`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I think I will just do something simpler.